# SOQL For Loops error?

Tags: apex, soql

I have a code that works fine:

```
 public with sharing class Send_noti_emails {

        public PageReference sendpassfail() {

            for (Inquery__c inquery : [SELECT Name,Id,Previous_user__c, Quilification__c,    Final_Email_Date__c, Email__c,First_Name__c, Last_Name__c]){
            }
        }
    }
```

But i need to change the code so that inquery  is a public declaration,

```
public with sharing class Send_noti_emails {
    public List<Inquery__c > u {get;set;}
    inquery = new Inquery__c();
    public PageReference sendpassfail() {

        for(inquery : [SELECT Name,Id,Previous_user__c, Quilification__c, Final_Email_Date__c, Email__c,First_Name__c, Last_Name__c]){
        }
    }
}
```

But this gives me an error telling me unexpected : at for(inquery : [SELECT 
Can someone tell me what i need to change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot the object name

```
for(inquery : [SELECT Name...];
```

Should be

```
for(Inquery__c inquery : [SELECT Name...];
```

> EDIT

If you want to use your controller property u (list of Inquery__c's) then you need to initialize the value in the constructor like below

```
public Send_noti_emails(){
    u = [SELECT Name,Id,Previous_user__c, Quilification__c, Final_Email_Date__c, Email__c,First_Name__c, Last_Name__c From Inquery__c];
}
```

**Then, you can reference that property in your for loop**

```
for(Inquery__c inquery : u){

}
```

Comment: Yes, thats what i had the code originally[see the first code], but i need to declare inquery as a public variable, because i need to call it from my test code. So if i do that, there is no need to do add Inquery__c anymore, is that correct?

Comment: Oh, ok, I see.  You need to initialize the value of your list in a class constructor.  Updated the code.

Comment: I added these two lines
public with sharing class Send_noti_emails {

public List<Inquery__c> u{get;set;}
22 u = [SELECT Name,Id,Previous_user__c, Quilification__c, Final_Email_Date__c, Email__c,First_Name__c, Last_Name__c];

But it tells me Error: unexpected token: '='  at line 22

Comment: Can you update the question so I can read it more clearly.  Its likely a simple thing just need to see your code.  Update the second code block with the exact code you are using, and then add the error below it

Comment: ok i fixed, i forgot to put the code into a public Send_noti_emails(){}, sorry about that

Comment: so is it working now?

Comment: Just to add, so your point is i can create the u variable in the test code and insert it. But how will i insert the inquery variable, if its not a public declaration, the code is looping through the Inquery_c database, which i have not created. So i am a bit confused?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what your asking.  Also, ff you have a question about test code for this class, you should ask another question.

Comment: Well yes there are no errors in the Apex code, but i still cant insert anything to the Inquery_databse, because it tells me the inquery variable doesnt exist!!. Because i have not made a public variable.

Comment: Ok i will post another question, i think i am not clear in this question.