# Error calling a private APEX variable from the test code?

Tags: apex, unit-test

I have an APEX code that loops through all records in the Inquery_c database as follows

```
public with sharing class Send_noti_emails {

  public List<Inquery__c> u{get;set;}

  public Send_noti_emails() {
     u = [SELECT Name,Id,Previous_user__c, Quilification__c, Final_Email_Date__c, Email__c,First_Name__c, Last_Name__c];
  }

  public PageReference sendpassfail() {
    for (Inquery__c inquery :u ){
    }
  }
}
```

I need to create a test code that covers this code so:

```
@isTest 
private class Send_noti_emailsTestClass {

  static testMethod void validateSend_noti_emails() {
    Send_noti_emails myNotes = new Send_noti_emails(); 

    Inquery__c inq = new Inquery__c(First_Name__c='Steve', Last_Name__c='Mike',Email__c='stevemike@gmail.com', Institution__c = 'InstitutionName', Position__c ='IT' ,Quilification__c='Qualified', Previous_user__c= true);
    insert inq ;    

    myNotes.inquery= inq;
    myNotes.sendpassfail() ;
  }
}
```

I get his error in the test code:

> Error: Compile Error: Variable does not exist: inquery at line 12
>   column 9 line 12 is :  myNotes.inquery= inq;

So I'mm guessing this is because inquery is not a public variable in the Apex code, is this correct? and how can i fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, SO I see from the last question [SOQL FOr Loop Erros](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/17927/soql-for-loops-error) you asked a short bit ago, where you are confused.  You don't need to set the inquery variable.  This is a variable within your For loop, that is instantiated when the for loop is run.  There is no need to set a value to this.  It is set in the constructor when the For loop is run.

In order to test this code, you need to add an Inquery__c object, which you are doing, and then call the method.

If you just remove this line

```
myNotes.inquery= inq;
```

and move your class constructor after your inquery insert

```
    Inquery__c inq = new Inquery__c(First_Name__c='Steve', Last_Name__c='Mike',Email__c='stevemike@gmail.com', Institution__c = 'InstitutionName', Position__c ='IT' ,Quilification__c='Qualified', Previous_user__c= true);
    insert inq ;
    Send_noti_emails myNotes = new Send_noti_emails();
```

You should no longer get the error and you should get full coverage on teh class.  All you have left to do is add some assertions and you are good to go.

Comment: So you guys are both right,

Comment: We both have the same answer, so of course. Though I was actually 65 seconds faster :p

Answer (score 6):

Your code never mentions a variable named "inquery", so I'd expect this to fail. You've got your order of operations backwards anyways. Try the following:

```
@isTest 
class Send_noti_emailsTestClass {
    static testMethod void validateSend_noti_emails() {
        Inquery__c inq = new Inquery__c(First_Name__c='Steve', Last_Name__c='Mike',Email__c='stevemike@gmail.com', Institution__c = 'InstitutionName', Position__c ='IT' ,Quilification__c='Qualified', Previous_user__c= true);
        insert inq ;
         Send_noti_emails myNotes = new Send_noti_emails(); 
        myNotes.sendpassfail() ;
    }
}
```

First, we insert the new record to test with, then call the constructor; this in turn will populate `u` in class.